# In the Android Studio 1.3 and later,what should be added in my .gitignore for a project?

Tags: android, gitignore

As the Android Studio is improved,now its latest version is 1.3.2,what should be in the .gitignore so that i can develop well?

Answer (score 2):

checkout this ignore file: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Android.gitignore

Also,

you can install this plugin: https://github.com/hsz/idea-gitignore

Comment: thanks,but is the .idea/misc.xml and .idea/encodings.xml need to be added?